# Use bubbles in UItextfield for auto-complete

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextfield

Is there any method to use bubbles programmatically for give suggestions in UITextfield.

Comment: What do you mean by bubbles?. auto correction? .

Comment: Yes I want to show auto complete suggestion as auto correction shows. suggestion should be my own list of text ,not from the dictionary http://cdn.damnyouautocorrect.com/img/iphone-scrotum.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `autocorrectionType` for UITextField.

```
yourTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

Comment: But i want to add my own suggestion list. How can i do that.

Comment: if you auto completion , you can look into http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values.

Comment: Yes i saw this but problem is there no enough space for add table in my user interface. That's why i try to use this.

Comment: I think there is no method to use bubbles for auto complete. So i used above suggestion method.